# Flexible round duct - What to use

Tags: hvac, ducts, central-heating

I'm re-routing some 10x3.25" duct through a bulkhead in my kitchen.  Planning to change over to 6" round duct for a 4'  segment that is relatively straight (no 90s).  It was my intention to use non-insulated UL 181 Class 1 (expandable aluminum), but my dad who (generally) knows his stuff said that's not to building code ( US - Pennsylvania ).  He couldn't explain why.

Reading the code it refers to flame spread index, not super helpful.  I imagine i will need to use the insulated ductwork but would like to understand why and what code/class adherence to look for.  Here's some info on the application:

- Forced air heating and AC supply air
- In interior wall (bulkhead), will be behind drywall
- 3-4' segment
- No sharp turns, but not a straight line either

Comment: This wall it is in is an interior wall, right?

Comment: Yes, inside a curtain wall on the first floor, in a 2 level house with balloon construction

Comment: I'd really like to use this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-4-in-x-8-ft-Semi-Rigid-Flexible-Aluminum-Duct-MFX48XHD12/203626514 - which is not the same as flexible foil duct, which us suitable for dryer vents

Comment: I take it the reason you can't use a rigid duct here is due to the need to make odd bends?

Comment: Its just a real tight space and its gotta weave through some studs.  I dont like the insulated stuff as much because it bulky and kinks easy.  I am gonna still going to give it a go with the rigid, it would just be way easier if I could use the semi-rigid.  Im going to assume its not to code because its not marketed for forced air systems, but id like to understand why ,

Comment: Do you have a local AHJ to concern yourself with, or just state Code adoptions?

Comment: Im in Pittsburgh, which according to this: http://pittsburghpa.gov/pli/pli-standards-codes. Only requires me to adhere to the statewide Uniform Construction Code

Comment: state UCC is mostly IRC 2015, and none of the PA amendments relate to ductwork.  If you could get a Code cite from your dad on this, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: So you're saying unless there is some other additional code I haven't identified, uninsulated semi-rigid flexible duct is allowed in interior walls?

Comment: Where are you trying to go with this duct-work? Is there a reason you need to run it through the bulkhead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### While Code will let you *use* such a product, you need to be careful when doing so to avoid giving your HVAC system a case of the wheezes

I can find nothing in the 2015 or 2018 IRC that forbids the use of uninsulated flexible duct conforming to UL 181 Class 1 (the SDI limit in Code is 200) for HVAC supply or return air ducts located within the conditioned envelope.  However, there *is* a major caveat with this sort of product: it can put a real drag on airflow through it when installed improperly!

In particular, in order to correctly use flexible ducting in an HVAC system, you *must* stretch it all the way out when installing it, and support it so that it doesn't sag or collapse back on itself later, otherwise you will get [excessive friction loss](https://www.energyvanguard.com/blog/the-science-of-sag-flex-duct-and-air-flow).  In other words, a sagging or unstretched flex duct restricts airflow through it, causing poor HVAC performance, and even excessive energy usage as many modern air handlers will fight to maintain airflow (CFM) despite the [radically excessive static pressure](https://oaktrust.library.tamu.edu/bitstream/handle/1969.1/5275/ESL-IC-06-11-133.pdf?sequence=4&isAllowed=y) needed to push air through the dodgy duct.

Comment: I agree and would add with more resistance and not insulated the ductwork may start creating moisture (think possible mold issues) but I have used non insulated flex ducting in conditioned air space for short runs where space and the routing made it impossible to use insulated or rigid and there was no problem, so it can be done.+